# `sum` extension on Measurement Sequence

Tags: swift, foundation, measurement

Here's what I've currently got. It has at least these problems:

1. It crashes, when used on an array of `Measurement<UnitType>`, when
   the units are mixed, such as with grams and milligrams.
2. Using an instance `zero` property isn't as good as a static alternative, which allows the return type to be the type's `zero`, instead of `nil`, for an empty sequence. I can't figure out if this is avoidable.

*I use the first extension because `Sequence.first` doesn't exist in the current version of Swift.*

```
import Foundation

public extension Sequence {
    var first: Iterator.Element? {
        return self.first{_ in true}
    }
}

public extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: SummableUsingInstanceZero {
    var sum: Iterator.Element? {
        guard let zero = first?.zero
        else {return nil}

        return self.reduce(zero, +)
    }
}

public protocol SummableUsingInstanceZero {
    static func + (_: Self, _: Self) -> Self

    var zero: Self {get}
}

extension Measurement: SummableUsingInstanceZero {
    public var zero: Measurement {
        return Measurement(
            value: 0,
            unit: unit
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum sequence of measurements with different unit types?

Comment: Sometimes. But only when the + is meaningful between them.

Comment: Swift 2.2 or 3.0? And an example where your code crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but the solution is still not built-in. Conforming to `AdditiveArithmetic` is the way to go!

```
import Foundation

extension Measurement: AdditiveArithmetic where UnitType: Dimension {
  public static var zero: Self {
    Self( value: 0, unit: .baseUnit() )
  }

  public static func += (measurement0: inout Self, measurement1: Self) {
    measurement0 = measurement0 + measurement1
  }

  public static func -= (measurement0: inout Self, measurement1: Self) {
    measurement0 = measurement0 - measurement1
  }
}
```